# Why is scrolling jumpy with images using JQTouch?

Tags: scroll, jqtouch

I have a bunch of images in a vertical row, and when you swipe to
scroll though them it's not smooth. It tends to jump up a little as
each pic comes into view.

However, once I scroll thru the images and back up it is smooth the second time around, like they are cached or something. I tried pre-loading images with no change.

Any ideas? Thanks.

```
<div id="pics">
<div class="toolbar">
<a href="#" class="back">Back</a>
<h3>Pics</h3>
</div>
<div id="wrap">
<h1 class="picname">Pic name</h1>
<p class="date">Jan 1, 2010</p>
<img src="1.png">

<h1 class="picname">Pic name</h1>
<p class="date">Jan 10, 2010</p>
<img src="10.png">

<h1 class="picname">Pic name</h1>
<p class="date">Jan 11, 2010</p>
<img src="11.png">

<h1 class="picname">Pic name</h1>
<p class="date">Jan 14, 2010</p>
<img src="14.png">

<h1 class="picname">Pic name</h1>
<p class="date">Jan 17, 2010</p>
<img src="17.png">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue with jqtouch, you can not change sizes drastically, I had that issue with dynamically loaded content, there are probably two solutions:

- provide image sizes
- load images one by one using onload/onabort handlers to go to next image

Comment: Thank for the response! So if I specify the width/height of each image it will work? Like <img src="blah.png" width="100px" height="100px">

Comment: it will should improve things, you wont know till you try it, you might also want to add css rule: body { background: transparent; }

Comment: Tried both...no go. Worth trying for sure tho. Thanks.

Comment: how did you preloaded images ? did you added them to manifest file ? maybe preloading with fixed sizes would help ?

Comment: I preloaded them with the javascript that comes with the JQTouch index file...it's in the head. I removed it before because i didnt think i needed it...maybe i do...but it's still wonky.